# How to save files into a mysql database using perl

Tags: mysql, linux, perl

I have a table PGM_MASTER, which has three columns

PGM_ID     | int(11)

PGM_ENV_ID | int(11)

PGM_TEXT   | mediumtext

I need your assistance in storing files/contents directly into mysql DB (say /tmp/t1.tst) for column 'PGM_TEXT' along with other columns in the row through perl. I too need to preserve the format of files which I intend to store.

Advanced thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
use DBI qw();
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);

my $content = read_file('/tmp/t1.tst', { binmode => ':raw' });
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=DBNAME', { AutoCommit => 1, RaiseError => 1, });
$dbh->do('insert into PGM_MASTER (PGM_TEXT) values (?)', {}, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you upload the files to your server and instead of saving the actual file in the DB just save a reference to its position in the file structure.

Say you have the structure

t1.tst

```
FOLDER  |
        | t1.tst
        | t2.tst
        | t3.tst
        | t4.tst
```

In your database you store the file path : FOLDER/t1.tst